# sed backreferencing with a command

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, sed

I have a string

```
STR="<trkpt lat="53.4829787887" lon="-113.518349362"><ele>682.0</ele><time>2020-01-09T01:00:01Z</time><speed>20.0</speed></trkpt>"
```

and im trying to replace the time with time+1 second.

To achieve this I have:

```
echo $STR | sed -e 's/<time>\(.*\)<\/time>/<time>'$(TZ=UTC date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" -d "\1 + 1 seconds")'<\/time>/g'
```

However I keep getting the error

```
date: invalid date ‘\\1 + 1 seconds’
```

Why is \1 being interpolated as \\1 under a subshell $()?

Could someone please help where I am wrong and help understand what's going on here.

Using gnu sed 4.4.

Comment: sed is not a tool designed to parse xml nor HTML

Comment: The shell is evaluating `$(TZ=UTC date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" -d "\1 + 1 seconds")` and *then* invoking `sed` with the result as the replacement string, I think

Comment: @GillesQuenot. In theory, back referencing should work the same way as a variable except that they are sequential placeholders for whats captured between the expression \\(\\).

Comment: `echo $STR | sed -r "s|<time>(.*)</time>|<time>$(date -d \1' + 1 seconds' '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')</time>|g"`

Answer (score 2):

What I would do using a proper XML parser and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) (don't use `sed` for this task):

### Input file

```
$ cat file.xml
<trkpt lat="53.4829787887" lon="-113.518349362">
  <ele>682.0</ele>
  <time>2020-01-09T01:00:01Z</time>
  <speed>20.0</speed>
</trkpt>
```

You can edit *on the fly* with `xmlstarlet ed -L -u ...`

### Commands

```
d=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/trkpt/time/text()' file.xml)
xmlstarlet ed -u '/trkpt/time/text()' -v $(
    TZ=UTC date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" -d "$d + 1 seconds"
) file.xml
```

### Output

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<trkpt lat="53.4829787887" lon="-113.518349362">
  <ele>682.0</ele>
  <time>2020-01-09T01:00:02Z</time>
  <speed>20.0</speed>
</trkpt>
```

Comment: Thanks @Giles Quenot !
I like the use of xmlstarlet and solves the problem!
However, i can't seem to understand why \1 is interpolated as \\1 in the subshell.

Comment: I feel you are wasting time on a specific artifact when you can learn something new and possibly more interesting :) My 2 cents.

Comment: Just trying to understand sed better. :)

Comment: It has nothing to do with sed: see @steeldriver's comment.

Comment: ...or to put it another way: try executing the command `TZ=UTC date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ" -d "\1 + 1 seconds"` in your shell.